# Parse XML with Apex

Tags: apex

I am having the following `XML`:

```
<Fields><orderTAb.SapService>Bhagya/Comp/Comp_Total##FALSE$$FR2:LB9000400008##FR098990</orderTAb.SapService>
</Fields>
```

I tried:

```
    //Parsing the OrderInfoTab.dataServicePage field
                 if (xsr.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT && xsr.getLocalName() == 'orderTAb.SapService'){
                     xsr.next();
                     if(xsr.hasText()){
                         string dataService = xsr.getText();
                          if(dataService.indexOf('Bhagya/Comp/Comp_Total') != -1){
                             ServiceCalculationsettingsH = 'Total';
                         }

    //Reading
    if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT && reader.getLocalName() == 'orderTAb.SapService'){
            reader.next();
            if(reader.hasText()){

            if (reader.getText() == 'Bhagya/Comp/Comp_Total')
            {
            values[10] = '"'+reader.getText()+'"';
            QC.ServiceCal = '"'+reader.getText()+'"';
            System.debug('QC.ServiceCal1--------------------'+QC.ServiceCal);
                }
                 if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.END_ELEMENT && reader.getLocalName() =='orderTAb.SapService') {
                temp += string.join(values,',') + '\n';
                lstQuoteContent.add(QC);
                System.debug('CHP-50:   ' +lstQuoteContent );
                break;
            }
            reader.next();

//To display Node(Tag)
if(lstquotecontent.size() > 0){
            for(Integer i = 0 ; i < lstquotecontent.size() ; i++){
             if(lstquotecontent[i].ServiceCal != NULL)
                    quotecontentLineItem.addChildElement('ServiceCal', null, null).addTextNode(lstquotecontent[i].ServiceCal);
                 else
                    quotecontentLineItem.addChildElement('ServiceCal', null, null).addTextNode('');
                }
```

Node get display properly in XML response but showing null value.

Comment: //Parsing the OrderInfoTab.dataServicePage field
                 if (xsr.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT && xsr.getLocalName() == 'orderTAb.SapService'){
                     xsr.next();
                     if(xsr.hasText()){
                         string dataService = xsr.getText();
                          if(dataService.indexOf('Bhagya/Comp/Comp_Total') != -1){
                             ServiceCalculationsettingsH = 'Total';
                         }

Comment: edit your question with code  please

Comment: and last part. What problem do you have? Any error message ?

Comment: The problem I craeted one node with name ServiceCal in that ,I want to fetch this value "Bhagya/Comp/Comp_Total##FALSE$$FR2:LB9000400008##FR098990". It showing null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Apex DOM parser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm) - it is way easier to get the code right:

```
String xml = '<Fields><orderTAb.SapService>Bhagya/Comp/Comp_Total##FALSE$$FR2:LB9000400008##FR098990</orderTAb.SapService></Fields>';
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(xml);
System.debug(doc.getRootElement().getChildElement('orderTAb.SapService', null).getText());
```

Comment: Requirement is only fetch a value which come into < ordertab.service> for response xml

Comment: @BhagyashreeShinde That is what the code I posted does: it picks out that value. Run it and see.